# swfobject.embedSWF doesn't load objects in IE7 and IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, swfobject

I have this code running great in ff, opera and chrome:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                      var swfUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?video_id=<?php echo bg_get_video_id($post->post_content)?>&enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer_<?php echo $i?>";


                      // allowScriptAccess must be set to allow the Javascript from one 
                      // domain to access the swf on the youtube domain
                      var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always", wmode: "opaque" };

                      // This sets the ID of the DOM object or embed tag to 'myytplayer'.
                      // You can use this ID to access the swf and call the player's API
                      var atts = { id: "ytplayer_<?php echo $i?>", class: "ytplayer"};
                      var flashvars = {};
                      swfobject.embedSWF(swfUrl, "ytdiv_<?php echo $i?>", "300", "120", "9", null, flashvars, params, atts);
                    });
                </script>
```

But not in Internet Explorer versions 7 and 8. It's a part of php file from Wordpress, but it's not important - video_id and ytdiv_ are all ok, it works in other browsers.

Is there anything I can do to make it work in IE? I don't have any ideas about what could have caused it.

Cheers,
Nebril

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:
`var atts = { id: "ytplayer_", "class": "ytplayer"};`

Type in quotes "class" and you are done. It helped me at least.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it's the same problem I had, but I had to upgrade to the latest version of swfobject, 2.2 I think it is now, that solved it for me.